# Finding the distance between two parallel 3D vectors

Tags: vectors

> Find the distance between the pairs of parallel lines:
>   $$
> r_a=\frac{x-2}{1}=\frac{y-1}{-1}=\frac{z-3}{2}\\
> r_b=\frac{x+1}{1}=\frac{y-3}{-1}=\frac{z-1}{2}
> $$

Let $A(2,1,3)$ sit on $r_a$ and let $P$ be a point where the perpendicular of $A$ meets $r_b$. Let $P$ have the position vector $p$:

$$
p = \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 3\\1\end{pmatrix} + \lambda\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1+\lambda \\ 3-\lambda\\1+2\lambda\end{pmatrix} \\
\vec{PA}=a-p=\begin{pmatrix}3-\lambda \\ -2+\lambda\\2-2\lambda\end{pmatrix}
$$

But $\vec{PA}$ is perpendicular to $r_b$ and $r_b$ is parallel to $(1,-1,2)$, so:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}3-\lambda \\ -2+\lambda\\2-2\lambda\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix}=0\\
3-\lambda+2-\lambda+4-4\lambda = 0\\
\lambda =  \frac{3}{2}
$$
Therefore:
$$
\vec{PA}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2}\\-1\end{pmatrix} \\
|\vec{PA}|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+1}=\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}
$$
But the answer given is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{14}$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple arithmetic error:

$$\vec{PA}=\begin{pmatrix}3-\lambda \\ -2+\lambda\\2-2\lambda\end{pmatrix}$$

Substituting $\lambda=\dfrac{3}{2}$ gives:
$$\vec{PA}=\begin{pmatrix}3-1\frac12\\-2+1\frac12\\2-2\cdot1\frac12\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\color{red}1\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2}\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$|\vec{PA}|=\sqrt{\frac{\color{red}9}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+1}=\frac12\sqrt{14}$$

Comment: D'oh :) thanks!